# Read multiple files and save data into one dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I am trying to read multiple files and then combine them into one data frame. The code that I am using is as follows:

```
library(plyr)
mydata = ldply(list.files(path="Data load for stations/data/Predicted",pattern = "txt"), function(filename) {
  dum = read.table(filename,skip=5, header=F, sep=" ")

  #If you want to add the filename as well on the column

  dum$filename = filename
  return(dum)
})
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'mobdata201001.txt': No such file or directory
```

The data files can be found on https://www.dropbox.com/sh/827kmkrwd0irehk/BFbftkks42

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried just loading one file with the path and filename you have provided? The error you are getting seems like it can't find the file. Maybe just tack on an extra "/" in the path?

Comment: If these are time series consistent with zoo then `read.zoo` can read in multiple files creating a single zoo object from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
library(plyr)
path <- "Data load for stations/data/Predicted/"
filenames <- paste0(path, list.files(path, pattern = "txt"))
mydata = ldply(filenames, function(filename) {
  dum = read.table(filename,skip=5, header=F, sep=" ")

  #If you want to add the filename as well on the column

  dum$filename = filename
  return(dum)
})
```

I think what is happening is you're generating a list of files relative to the path in `list.files`, and then asking `read.table` to take the filename without the rest of the path...

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can use argument `full.names` in `list.files`:

```
list.files(path="Data load for stations/data/Predicted",
           pattern = "txt", full.names=TRUE)
```

It will add automatically the full path before the file name.